# Fetching data in the background on app launch in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When my react-native app launches, I need to fetch data from a remote API.  Should I trigger this in the `componentDidMount` method of my main component?  Are there other recommended options?

Additionally, does React provide a way to keep track of all outstanding network calls (ie, unresolved Promises), and a way to cancel them if needed?  Or would this be considered the programmer's responsibility, so that I would need to write the code myself or use another library for it?

Answer (score 3):

Jonah,

Yes, this should probably be done in the componentDidMount. When the response arrives, store the data in state (this will trigger a render to update your UI).

I am not aware of a way to keep track of all outstanding network calls. We've been handling this ourselves.